# Can anybody explain me this brute force using bitmask

Tags: c++, algorithm, brute-force, bitmask

Question A of Educational Codeforces Round 105 (Rated for Div. 2).
Um_nik solved this question with this brute force approach and I don't fully understand it.
I know what is a bitmask but I am confused at if ((mask >> (int)(s[i] - 'A')) & 1) and ok &= bal >= 0.
The link to the question is: https://codeforces.com/contest/1494/problem/A

```
    cin >> s;
    int n = (int)s.length();
    //cout << s << endl;
    for (int mask = 0; mask < (1 << 3); mask++) {
        int bal = 0;
        bool ok = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if ((mask >> (int)(s[i] - 'A')) & 1)
                bal++;
            else
                bal--;
            ok &= bal >= 0;
        }
        ok &= bal == 0;
        if (ok) {
            printf("YES\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("NO\n");
```

Comment: `ok &= bal >= 0` -> `ok = ok & bal >= 0` -> `if (bal < 0) ok = false`

Answer (score 2):

I know the problem!

The `m` has the range of `0b000 ~ 0b111`, and the i-th bit means if `'A' + i` is the sign `(` (if not, it is the sign `)`).

> for example, the `m = 0b010` means `{'A': ')', 'B': '(', 'C': ')'}`. I need to use `m[CHAR]` to mean `(m >> (CHAR - 'A') & 1) ? '(' : ')'`, so `m['B'] == '('`.

We know that `s[i]` is the i-th character in the string `s`, so `m >> (s[i] - 'A') & 1` has the meaning that `m[s[i]]`, and will get if the i-th character means sign `(`.

> for example, the `s = "ABBC"`, `m = 0b010`, and `i = 2`, so `s[i] == 'B'`, you will know that `m >> ('B' - 'A') & 1 == m['B'] == '('`

At the end, we need to set a state that it is `0` at begin, and then add `1` if meet `(`, or minus `1` if meet `)`. And if the state is always `>= 0`, and at the end it is `== 0`, then it has the corrent answer, that's why we need print `"YES"` and return.

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind the algorithm is to try all possibilities for the letters A, B and C. Meaning A can be '(' or ')', same for B and C.

Thus we have 8 possibilities,

```
A B C   in binary
( ( (   0 0 0
( ( )   0 0 1
( ) (   0 1 0
( ) )   0 1 1
) ( (   1 0 0 
) ( )   1 0 1
) ) (   1 1 0
) ) )   1 1 1
```

Practically, the author says '(' is 0 and ')' is 1, or the opposite, to cover, in binary, the 8 possibilities, meaning from 000 to 111. Why "*or the opposite*"? Because as you can see above, if a mask gives A:(, B:( and C:) for `001`, another mask, `110` will render A:), B:) and C:(.

Thus the *mask* goes from 0 to 8-1 (`(1 << 3)-1`), or, in binary, 000 to 111.

For instance, 000 means A, B and C are all opening (or closing) parentheses, and 110 would be in this case `))(`, for `ABC` (or `(()`).

For a given mask (outer loop), the inner loop `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` goes over all characters, and applies the current mask. `(mask >> (int)(s[i] - 'A')) & 1` simply tells, for the current mask, if the letter at *i* is a `(` or a `)`.

That is, `(int)(s[i] - 'A')` gives `0` for A, `1` for B and `2` for C. Thus, A gets the value of the bit a position 0 (the rightmost bit) of the mask, B the 2<sup>nd</sup> one and C the 3<sup>rd</sup> (leftmost).

```
      C  B  A
mask b2 b1 b0
```

The variable `bal` is probably *balance*. Each time an "opening" (`(`) letter is met, `bal` is incremented, and decremented for a `)`.

The `ok &= bal >= 0`, in the inner loop, ensures that at any time we don't have more closing that we has opening parentheses. Thus that prevents `ABBA` from being qualified.

The `ok &= bal == 0`, after the inner loop, ensures that we have the same number of opening and closing parentheses.

Again, just to avoid confusion, the mask tries all possibilities, thus `ABAB` wouldn't qualify as `)()(`, for, say, a mask `001`, but then the mask reaches `010` that gives `()()` which qualifies.

Note: *mask* could well start at `001` (1) and end at `110` (6) since the `000` (0) and `111` (7) values will never work (assigning all A, B and C to the same parenthese cannot work).